# Compiling content without XNA

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I have a Content Project for an XNA game, but I'm embedding the game inside a WinForm so I'm not actually using the Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Game class.

How can I make the Content project build with the WinForm's project? I tried adding it as a reference, but the Project isn't listed to be added.

To make it clear, I have two projects in my solution:

- KinectGraphics
- XNARenderContent

How can I make XNARenderContent build along with my KinectGraphics' project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a `WinForms` application, can I draw your attention to [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20101018080554/http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) article.

You can change the `Build Order` if this is causing you a problem.

If you are struggling to get the `Content` project in your `WinForms` application as a reference, then I would definitely take a look at the link above.